# Trying to implement a shell with two or more pipes but the program hangs - C

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, fork

I've successfully implemented a small shell program with the ability to implement a pipe between two commands like

> ls -l | wc -l

However, when I try to implement one or more shells so I can, for instance, do

> ls -l | wc -l | wc -l

my program hangs until I ^C.

I've been wrapping my head around this for hours now and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. My approach was to create as many child processes as commands I have, all with the same father. Here's my full code:

```
#define ARGVMAX 100
#define LINESIZE 1024
#define PIPESYMB "|"
#define EXITSYMB "exit"


int makeargv(char *s, char *argv[]) {
    if ( s==NULL || argv==NULL || ARGVMAX==0)
        return -1;

    int ntokens = 0;
    argv[ntokens]=strtok(s, " \t\n");
    while ( (argv[ntokens]!=NULL) && (ntokens<ARGVMAX) ) {
        ntokens++;
        argv[ntokens]=strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }

    argv[ntokens] = NULL;
    return ntokens;
}

void changeOutput(int mypipe[]) {
    dup2(mypipe[1], 1);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]);
}

void changeInput(int mypipe[]) {
    dup2(mypipe[0], 0);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    close(mypipe[0]);
}

void pipeFork(char *argv[], int i, int mypipe[]) {
    int h = i;
    int mypipe1[2];
    int found = 0;
    while((argv[h] != NULL) && !found) {
        if(!(strcmp(argv[h], PIPESYMB))) {
            argv[h] = NULL;
            found = 1;
        }
        h++;
    }
    if (pipe(mypipe1)==-1) 
                abort();
    switch ( fork() ) {
                    case -1: 
                        perror("fork error"); 
                        exit(1);
                    case 0:
                        changeInput(mypipe);
                        if(found)
                            changeOutput(mypipe1);
                        execvp( argv[i], &argv[i] );
                        perror("exec");
                        exit(1);
                    default:
                        if(found)
                            pipeFork(argv, h, mypipe1);
    }
    close(mypipe1[0]);
    close(mypipe1[1]); 
    wait(NULL);
}
void runcommand(char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int mypipe[2];
    int found = 0;
    if(!(strcmp(argv[0], EXITSYMB))) 
        exit(0);
    if (pipe(mypipe)==-1) 
                abort();
    while((argv[i] != NULL) && !found) {
        if(!(strcmp(argv[i], PIPESYMB))) {
            argv[i] = NULL;
            found = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    switch ( fork() ) {
        case -1: 
            perror("fork error"); 
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            if(found)
                changeOutput(mypipe);
            execvp( argv[0], argv );
            perror("exec");
            exit(1);
        default: 
             if(found)
               pipeFork(argv, i, mypipe);

    }
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]); 
    wait(NULL);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char* av[ARGVMAX];

    printf("> "); fflush(stdout);
    while ( fgets ( line, LINESIZE, stdin) != NULL ) {
        if ( makeargv( line, av) > 0 ) runcommand( av );
        printf("> "); fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my first time working with multi processes and, albeit this might have not been the best approach, I'm just now super curious has to where the mistake is.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you've long since resolved this, but…

#### Diagnosis

The primary problem, as ever, is not closing enough file descriptors.  A secondary problem is demonstrating this.  I took your original code and added a fair amount of instrumentation — printing (to standard error).  The messages are prefixed with the PID of the process doing the printing, which is rather important when there are multiple processes around.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARGVMAX 100
#define LINESIZE 1024
#define PIPESYMB "|"
#define EXITSYMB "exit"

static void dump_fds(int max_fd)
{
    char buffer[64];
    char *base = buffer + snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d: fds ", (int)getpid());
    for (int i = 0; i < max_fd; i++)
    {
        struct stat sb;
        if (fstat(i, &sb) == 0)
            *base++ = 'o';
        else
            *base++ = '-';
    }
    *base = '\0';
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
}

static void dump_argv(const char *tag, char **argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s:\n", (int)getpid(), tag);
    int i = 0;
    while (*argv)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", (int)getpid(), i++, *argv++);
    dump_fds(20);
}

static int makeargv(char *s, char *argv[])
{
    if (s == NULL || argv == NULL || ARGVMAX == 0)
        return -1;

    int ntokens = 0;
    argv[ntokens] = strtok(s, " \t\n");
    while ((argv[ntokens] != NULL) && (ntokens < ARGVMAX))
    {
        ntokens++;
        argv[ntokens] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }

    argv[ntokens] = NULL;
    return ntokens;
}

static void changeOutput(int mypipe[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: (%d closed) (%d to 1)\n", (int)getpid(), mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    dup2(mypipe[1], 1);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]);
}

static void changeInput(int mypipe[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: (%d to 0) (%d closed)\n", (int)getpid(), mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    dup2(mypipe[0], 0);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    close(mypipe[0]);
}

static void wait_for(int pid)
{
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: child %d exit status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
        if (pid == 0 || corpse == pid)
            break;
    }
}

static void pipeFork(char *argv[], int i, int mypipe[])
{
    int h = i;
    int mypipe1[2];
    int found = 0;
    dump_argv("pipeFork", &argv[h]);
    while ((argv[h] != NULL) && !found)
    {
        if (!(strcmp(argv[h], PIPESYMB)))
        {
            argv[h] = NULL;
            found = 1;
        }
        h++;
    }
    if (pipe(mypipe1) == -1)
        abort();
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s - pipe (%d,%d)\n", (int)getpid(), __func__, mypipe1[0], mypipe1[1]);
    int pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: pipeFork - child\n", (int)getpid());
        changeInput(mypipe);
        if (found)
            changeOutput(mypipe1);
        dump_argv("pipefork:execvp", &argv[i]);
        execvp(argv[i], &argv[i]);
        perror("exec");
        exit(1);
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: forked child %d\n", (int)getpid(), pid);
        if (found)
        {
            dump_argv("recurse-pipeFork", &argv[h]);
            pipeFork(argv, h, mypipe1);
        }
        break;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: pipeFork: close %d %d\n", (int)getpid(), mypipe1[0], mypipe1[1]);
    close(mypipe1[0]);
    close(mypipe1[1]);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: waiting in pipeFork for %d\n", (int)getpid(), pid);
    wait_for(0);
}

static void runcommand(char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int mypipe[2];
    int found = 0;
    if (!(strcmp(argv[0], EXITSYMB)))
        exit(0);
    if (pipe(mypipe) == -1)
        abort();
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s - pipe (%d,%d)\n", (int)getpid(), __func__, mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    while ((argv[i] != NULL) && !found)
    {
        if (!(strcmp(argv[i], PIPESYMB)))
        {
            argv[i] = NULL;
            found = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    int pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: runcommand - child\n", (int)getpid());
        if (found)
            changeOutput(mypipe);
        dump_argv("about to exec", argv);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        perror("exec");
        exit(1);
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: forked child %d\n", (int)getpid(), pid);
        if (found)
        {
            dump_argv("call-pipeFork", &argv[i]);
            pipeFork(argv, i, mypipe);
        }
        break;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: runcommand: close %d %d\n", (int)getpid(), mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: waiting in runcommand for %d\n", (int)getpid(), pid);
    wait_for(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char *av[ARGVMAX];

    printf("> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if (makeargv(line, av) > 0)
        {
            dump_argv("after reading", av);
            runcommand(av);
        }
        printf("> ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `dump_fds()` function builds the buffer and prints a single line because when it was outputting characters piecemeal, I got interference between processes running the loop at the same time.

With the instrumentation in place, we can see what happens with `ls | wc`:

```
$ ./shell23
> ls | wc
6418: after reading:
6418: argv[0] = "ls"
6418: argv[1] = "|"
6418: argv[2] = "wc"
6418: fds ooo-----------------
6418: runcommand - pipe (3,4)
6418: forked child 6419
6418: call-pipeFork:
6418: argv[0] = "wc"
6418: fds ooooo---------------
6418: pipeFork:
6418: argv[0] = "wc"
6418: fds ooooo---------------
6418: pipeFork - pipe (5,6)
6418: forked child 6420
6418: pipeFork: close 5 6
6419: runcommand - child
6419: (3 closed) (4 to 1)
6418: waiting in pipeFork for 6420
6419: about to exec:
6419: argv[0] = "ls"
6419: fds ooo-----------------
6420: pipeFork - child
6420: (3 to 0) (4 closed)
6420: pipefork:execvp:
6420: argv[0] = "wc"
6420: fds ooo--oo-------------
6418: child 6419 exit status 0x0000
6418: runcommand: close 3 4
6418: waiting in runcommand for 6419
       8       8      81
6418: child 6420 exit status 0x0000
> 
> …
```

If you look at the fds output for process 6420 just before the `execvp()`, you can see that file descriptors 5 and 6 are still open.  Fortunately, in this case, it doesn't do any damage; `ls` (6419) has just three desriptors open (as it should) and when it exits, the input for `wc` (6420) is closed.

The trace for `ls | wc | wc` is more problematic:

```
> …
>
> ls | wc | wc
6418: after reading:
6418: argv[0] = "ls"
6418: argv[1] = "|"
6418: argv[2] = "wc"
6418: argv[3] = "|"
6418: argv[4] = "wc"
6418: fds ooo-----------------
6418: runcommand - pipe (3,4)
6418: forked child 6421
6418: call-pipeFork:
6418: argv[0] = "wc"
6418: argv[1] = "|"
6418: argv[2] = "wc"
6418: fds ooooo---------------
6418: pipeFork:
6418: argv[0] = "wc"
6418: argv[1] = "|"
6418: argv[2] = "wc"
6418: fds ooooo---------------
6418: pipeFork - pipe (5,6)
6418: forked child 6422
6421: runcommand - child
6421: (3 closed) (4 to 1)
6418: recurse-pipeFork:
6418: argv[0] = "wc"
6418: fds ooooooo-------------
6418: pipeFork:
6418: argv[0] = "wc"
6418: fds ooooooo-------------
6421: about to exec:
6418: pipeFork - pipe (7,8)
6421: argv[0] = "ls"
6421: fds ooo-----------------
6422: pipeFork - child
6422: (3 to 0) (4 closed)
6418: forked child 6423
6418: pipeFork: close 7 8
6418: waiting in pipeFork for 6423
6422: (5 closed) (6 to 1)
6422: pipefork:execvp:
6422: argv[0] = "wc"
6422: fds ooo-----------------
6423: pipeFork - child
6423: (5 to 0) (6 closed)
6423: pipefork:execvp:
6423: argv[0] = "wc"
6423: fds ooooo--oo-----------
6418: child 6421 exit status 0x0000
6418: pipeFork: close 5 6
6418: waiting in pipeFork for 6422
^C
$
```

Processes 6421 (`ls`) and 6422 (`wc` the first) are OK, but 6423 has file descriptors 3, 4, 7, 8 open (as well as 0, 1, 2), and this time, these cause trouble; one of them is the writing end of the standard input pipe, so EOF cannot be reported because there's a process (6423) that could write to the pipe if it weren't hung up on reading from it.

There's also a chance that the parent process (6418 in this example) is keeping pipe file descriptors open inappropriately — a modified version of the code used working on the prescription (below) showed the parent process with descriptors 0-4 open when waiting for the second `wc` to complete.

#### Prescription

The simple prescription is "close enough file descriptors".

Actually closing the correct file descriptors is a bigger problem.  On the recursive call to `pipeFork()` from within `pipeFork()`, it is important to
close the `mypipe` file descriptors; the recursive function uses the `mypipe1` file descriptors passed in and knows nothing about the others and doesn't need them.  Similarly, the parent shell must close the `mypipe` file descriptors (as well as the `mypipe1` file descriptors) before waiting.
Also, it is sensible that the last child does not create an unused pipe as happened before.

```
/* SO 4672-0692 */

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARGVMAX 100
#define LINESIZE 1024
#define PIPESYMB "|"
#define EXITSYMB "exit"

static void logmsg(const char *func, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    char *base = buffer + snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d: %s(): ", (int)getpid(), func);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(base, sizeof(buffer) - (base - buffer), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
}

static void dump_fds(const char *func, int max_fd)
{
    char buffer[64] = "fds ";
    char *base = buffer + strlen(buffer);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_fd; i++)
    {
        struct stat sb;
        if (fstat(i, &sb) == 0)
            *base++ = 'o';
        else
            *base++ = '-';
    }
    *base = '\0';
    logmsg(func, "%s", buffer);
}

static void dump_argv(const char *func, const char *tag, char **argv)
{
    logmsg(func, "%s:", tag);
    int i = 0;
    while (*argv != 0)
        logmsg(func, "argv[%d] = \"%s\"", i++, *argv++);
    dump_fds(func, 20);
}

static int makeargv(char *s, char *argv[])
{
    if (s == NULL || argv == NULL || ARGVMAX == 0)
        return -1;

    int ntokens = 0;
    argv[ntokens] = strtok(s, " \t\n");
    while ((argv[ntokens] != NULL) && (ntokens < ARGVMAX))
    {
        ntokens++;
        argv[ntokens] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }

    argv[ntokens] = NULL;
    return ntokens;
}

static void changeOutput(int mypipe[])
{
    logmsg(__func__, "(%d closed) (%d to 1)", mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    dup2(mypipe[1], 1);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]);
}

static void changeInput(int mypipe[])
{
    logmsg(__func__, "(%d to 0) (%d closed)", mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    dup2(mypipe[0], 0);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    close(mypipe[0]);
}

static void wait_for(const char *func, int pid)
{
    int corpse;
    int status;
    dump_fds(__func__, 20);
    while ((corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) > 0)
    {
        logmsg(func, "child %d exit status 0x%.4X", corpse, status);
        if (pid == 0 || corpse == pid)
            break;
    }
}

static void pipeFork(char *argv[], int i, int mypipe[])
{
    int h = i;
    int mypipe1[2];
    int found = 0;
    dump_argv(__func__, "entry", &argv[h]);
    while ((argv[h] != NULL) && !found)
    {
        if (!(strcmp(argv[h], PIPESYMB)))
        {
            argv[h] = NULL;
            found = 1;
        }
        h++;
    }
    if (found)
    {
        if (pipe(mypipe1) == -1)
            abort();
        logmsg(__func__, "pipe (%d,%d)", mypipe1[0], mypipe1[1]);
    }
    int pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        logmsg(__func__, "- child");
        changeInput(mypipe);
        if (found)
            changeOutput(mypipe1);
        dump_argv(__func__, "execvp", &argv[i]);
        execvp(argv[i], &argv[i]);
        perror("exec");
        exit(1);
    default:
        logmsg(__func__, "forked child %d", pid);
        if (found)
        {
            close(mypipe[0]);
            close(mypipe[1]);
            dump_argv(__func__, "recurse", &argv[h]);
            pipeFork(argv, h, mypipe1);
        }
        break;
    }
    if (found)
    {
        logmsg(__func__, "close %d %d", mypipe1[0], mypipe1[1]);
        close(mypipe1[0]);
        close(mypipe1[1]);
    }
    logmsg(__func__, "close %d %d", mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    logmsg(__func__, "waiting for %d", pid);
    wait_for(__func__, pid);
}

static void runcommand(char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int mypipe[2];
    int found = 0;
    fflush(0);
    if (!(strcmp(argv[0], EXITSYMB)))
        exit(0);
    if (pipe(mypipe) == -1)
        abort();
    logmsg(__func__, "pipe (%d,%d)", mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    while ((argv[i] != NULL) && !found)
    {
        if (!(strcmp(argv[i], PIPESYMB)))
        {
            argv[i] = NULL;
            found = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    int pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        logmsg(__func__, "- child");
        if (found)
            changeOutput(mypipe);
        dump_argv(__func__, "execvp", argv);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        perror("exec");
        exit(1);
    default:
        logmsg(__func__, "forked child %d", pid);
        if (found)
        {
            dump_argv(__func__, "call-pipeFork", &argv[i]);
            pipeFork(argv, i, mypipe);
        }
        break;
    }
    logmsg(__func__, "close %d %d", mypipe[0], mypipe[1]);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    logmsg(__func__, "waiting for %d", pid);
    wait_for(__func__, pid);
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char *av[ARGVMAX];

    printf("> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if (makeargv(line, av) > 0)
        {
            dump_argv(__func__, "after reading", av);
            runcommand(av);
        }
        printf("> ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

When built and run, a sample trace from `shell79` is:

```
$ ./shell79
> ls | wc | wc
7182: main(): after reading:
7182: main(): argv[0] = "ls"
7182: main(): argv[1] = "|"
7182: main(): argv[2] = "wc"
7182: main(): argv[3] = "|"
7182: main(): argv[4] = "wc"
7182: main(): fds ooo-----------------
7182: runcommand(): pipe (3,4)
7182: runcommand(): forked child 7183
7182: runcommand(): call-pipeFork:
7182: runcommand(): argv[0] = "wc"
7182: runcommand(): argv[1] = "|"
7182: runcommand(): argv[2] = "wc"
7182: runcommand(): fds ooooo---------------
7182: pipeFork(): entry:
7182: pipeFork(): argv[0] = "wc"
7182: pipeFork(): argv[1] = "|"
7182: pipeFork(): argv[2] = "wc"
7182: pipeFork(): fds ooooo---------------
7182: pipeFork(): pipe (5,6)
7182: pipeFork(): forked child 7184
7182: pipeFork(): recurse:
7182: pipeFork(): argv[0] = "wc"
7182: pipeFork(): fds ooo--oo-------------
7182: pipeFork(): entry:
7182: pipeFork(): argv[0] = "wc"
7183: runcommand(): - child
7183: changeOutput(): (3 closed) (4 to 1)
7182: pipeFork(): fds ooo--oo-------------
7183: runcommand(): execvp:
7183: runcommand(): argv[0] = "ls"
7183: runcommand(): fds ooo-----------------
7182: pipeFork(): forked child 7185
7182: pipeFork(): close 5 6
7182: pipeFork(): waiting for 7185
7184: pipeFork(): - child
7184: changeInput(): (3 to 0) (4 closed)
7182: wait_for(): fds ooo-----------------
7184: changeOutput(): (5 closed) (6 to 1)
7184: pipeFork(): execvp:
7184: pipeFork(): argv[0] = "wc"
7184: pipeFork(): fds ooo-----------------
7185: pipeFork(): - child
7185: changeInput(): (5 to 0) (6 closed)
7185: pipeFork(): execvp:
7185: pipeFork(): argv[0] = "wc"
7185: pipeFork(): fds ooo-----------------
       1       3      25
7182: pipeFork(): child 7185 exit status 0x0000
7182: pipeFork(): close 5 6
7182: pipeFork(): close 3 4
7182: pipeFork(): waiting for 7184
7182: wait_for(): fds ooo-----------------
7182: pipeFork(): child 7184 exit status 0x0000
7182: runcommand(): close 3 4
7182: runcommand(): waiting for 7183
7182: wait_for(): fds ooo-----------------
7182: runcommand(): child 7183 exit status 0x0000
> ^D
$
```

This looks clean; there are no stray open file descriptors.